# Can autotests reuse code of the application?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests

Unit tests are strongly connected to the existing code of the application, written by developers. But what about UI and API automated tests (integration tests)? Does anybody think, that it's acceptable to re-use code of the application in separate automation solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be no. UI tests follow the UI, go to that page, input that value in that textbox, press that button, I should see this text. You don't need anything code related for this. All this should be done against some acceptance criteria so you should already know what to expect, without looking at any code.

For the API integration tests you would call the endpoints, with some payloads and then check the results. You don't need references to any code for this. The API should be documented and explain very well what endpoints are available, what the payloads look like and what you can expect to get back.

I am not sure why you'd think about reusing application code inside an automation project.

Ok, so after clarifications, you're talking about reusing models only, not actual code. This is not a bad idea, it can actually help, as long as these nuget packages do not bring in any other dependencies.

Code Reusability is a great concept but it's very hard to get right in practice. Models typically come with adnotations which require other packages which are of course not needed in an automation project. So, if you can get nuget packages without extra dependencies, so literally data models only and nothing else then that does work. Anything more than that and it will create issues so I'd push back on that

Comment: Actually, I don't want to reuse application code. But some developers (who probably cannot understand the gist of automation, or think about automation as unit tests) forces QA automation engineers to use their code (added  via nuget to automation solution) because "it reduces duplication and bla-bla-bla". I think, that this part of code may contain some bugs and finally we will get false-positive tests, because autotests will work incorrectly the same way, as their code works. What do you think?

Comment: I still don't understand why you need the application code for an automation project. Do a POC and add a couple of automated tests,, i bet you won't find any reason to use those nuget packages

Comment: From developers point of view there is a reason. E.g., developers have class to describe model that will be sent as json in the API endpoint. Very similar class exists in the automation solution, and the response (that we need to test) will parsed to instance of this class, and then it will be verified. Idea of developers is not to create 2 similar classes (in the code of application, and in the automation code), because it's duplication. But i'm sure, such optimization is pitfall: if there is defect in the code of application, autotest may also work incorrectly and give false positive result.

Comment: ok, added more to my answer based on additional clarifications